# После перезапуска сервера Munin не хочет запускаться

Tags: linux, debian, munin

После перезапуска сервера Munin не хочет запускаться. Выдает следующее:

```
Unit munin-node.service entered failed state.
munin-node.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
Failed to start Munin Node.
```

В чем может быть проблема и как возобновить работу Munin?

Comment: очевидно, что проблема в том, что «munin-node.service never wrote its PID file». откуда брали пакет?

Comment: пакет собирался из исходников

Comment: как это можно исправить?

Comment: например, собрать правильно. а ещё лучше — установить из репозитория дистрибутива (если пакет там, конечно, есть).

Comment: проблема в том, что до перезагрузки он прекрасно работал. можно как-нибудь обойтись малой кровью?

Comment: начните с просмотра логов, которые пишет программа.

Comment: посмотрите существует ли каталог /run/munin/ и файл в нем - munin-node.pid если есть удалите его и перезапустите сервис, если каталога нет, то стоит посмотреть в /etc/systemd/system/munin-node.service параметр PIDFile чему равен и проверить права на этот каталог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснилось, что проблема была в отсутствии папки, в которой запускался PID-файл с Munin. Проблему решил создав папку /run/munin и назначив ей пользователя/права Munin.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Правда в последнем коментарии к вопросу мне показалось что-то похожее)

Comment: так и есть) с меня плюс в карму)